# synthesis returns error: non synthesizable type

Tags: xilinx, http-live-streaming, vivado

I have data structure in my top function which I want to accelerate by running it on the FPGA.

I have a data structure called Rectangle which contains itself a data structure.

```
typedef struct rectangle Rectangle;
struct rectangle {
    Point *position;
    int height;
    int width;
    Rectangle *suivant;
};
```

`Point` is also a data structure :

```
typedef struct point Point;
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point *suivant;
};
```

My top function takes into argument a pointer to the data structure `Rectangle`.

Here is my top function :

```
void mise_a_jour_coef_tab(Case_tab tab[NBCOL][NBLIG],Rectangle *zone_occupe)
{
    int i,j;
    int val;

    for(j=zone_occupe->position->x;j<zone_occupe->position->x+zone_occupe->width;j++){
        if(zone_occupe->position->y==0 || tab[j][zone_occupe->position->y-1].coef<0)
            val=1;
        else
            val=tab[j][zone_occupe->position->y-1].coef+1;

        for(i=zone_occupe->position->y;i<NBLIG;i++){            
            if(tab[j][i].free==0){
                tab[j][i].coef=val;
                val++;
            }           
            else{
                val=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run

```
c synthesis
```

there are 3 errors :

> Argument 'zone_occupe' of function 'mise_a_jour_coef_tab' has an unsynthesizable type (possible cause(s): structure variable cannot be decomposed due to unsupported type conversion or memory copy operation).
>
> Argument 'zone_occupe' has an unsynthesizable type '%struct.rectangle.1.6.8 = type { %struct.point.0.5.7*, i32, ...' (possible cause(s): pointer to pointer or global pointer).
>
> Synthesizability check failed.

Can somebody help me how I can fix this ?
How can we include data structures in top function of vivado HLS ?

Comment: Not without being able to see your code.

Comment: Thank you very much @rene for formatting correctly my code. I am new here. Next time, i will ask it properly.

Comment: Thank you @rene, that's what i was doing!

Comment: You should also include the code for your "top function".  
I'm not experienced with HLS tools but I would suspect this is an issue with using pointers.  Think about what the hardware is going to do and pointers aren't probably the greatest representation.  You don't want your accelerator reaching out into memory and doing stuff, you want to pass the accelerator something and get it back with changes made, then put that in memory.  I'm making a lot of assumptions here about what you're actually doing, but that's my best guess.

Comment: @Ian I added my top function.

Comment: @AbdulWahab, again I don't use HLS tools so I can' say for sure, but if you read your error messages it lists "pointer to pointer" as a possible cause.  So rewrite your structures to hold values instead of pointers and give it a try.  Right now you're passing a pointer to a structure, that contains a pointer to a structure, that contains a pointer to a structure.  It doesn't surprise me that it can't synthesize that.

Comment: I changed the prototype of my function to hold values instead of pointer which solved my problem but still i do need to know how to accelerate a function with multiple pointers in order to accelerate other functions.